# Scraping multiple urls using Rselenium

Tags: r, loops, web-scraping, rselenium

I cannot scrape the content of multiples urls using RSelenium. If I scrape each webpage individually, I get the expected outcome. However, when trying to use the loop, I do not get results

## Setting the remote browser

```
library(RSelenium)

#Setting the remote browser
remDr <- RSelenium::remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "192.168.99.100",
                                 port = 4444L,
                                 browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()
```

## Urls of the website I want to scrape

```
links <- c('https://www.lasillavacia.com/node/68077', 'https://www.lasillavacia.com/node/56774', 'https://www.lasillavacia.com/node/57833')
```

## Loop I am using

```
test_silla <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:(length(links))) {
  remDr$navigate(paste0(links[[i]]))
  Sys.sleep(1)
  print(i)
  content_test <- remDr$findElements(using = "css selector", value = ".article-date")
  content_test2 <- data.frame(url = unlist(sapply(content_test, function(x){x$getElementText()})))
  Sys.sleep(1)
  test_silla <- rbind(test_silla, content_test2)
}
```

## By single page, it works without problem

```
url_test <- 'https://www.lasillavacia.com/node/68077'
remDr$navigate(url_test)

content_test <- remDr$findElements(using = "css selector", value = '.article-date')
content_test <-  sapply(url_test, function(x){x$getElementText()})
```

I have used a similar code for scraping another website with RSelenium and it worked. Could anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: First never use `rbind` in a loop to grow objects as it runs excessive copies in memory. Second, you assign to a different named object so only the last results would show. Possibly no results exist on very last link. Please show working code of non-loop version.

Comment: I edited the post and included the code on non-loop version. I also checked and assigned the same name to the object (but still does not work). Could you please guide me how can I do it? Thanks!

Comment: link https://www.lasillavacia.com/node/68077 not working, can you fix it?